# Integral involving the Legendre Polynomials

Tags: special-functions

I'm trying to compute the following integral:

$\int_a^{+\infty} \frac{dt}{(P_\lambda(\tanh{t}))^2}$

and to be honest I have no idea on how I should attack this problem. Is there any reference that I could look at to get on track (or where I'll find the answer for this although I have little hope) ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Set $u=\tanh t$, this will turn your integrand in a rational function, with $dt=du/(1-u^2)$. The rest is 'standard'.